# Factory reset AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to delete everything I have done on my AWS account except for credits and root user stuff.  This includes IAM users, EC2 stuff, S3 stuff, route 53 etc. How can I do this without having to scour the AWS account to find everything? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are tools such as [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) and [cloud-nuke](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke).

Warning: these open source tools are **not** provided by AWS, you should take every precaution to ensure that nothing critical gets deleted, and you are responsible for your choices and actions.

There is specific guidance on [How do I terminate all my resources before closing my AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-resources-account-closure/) which you could use, and simply not close the AWS account after terminating your resources.

You also have the option to [close your AWS account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/).

Comment: Unbeliavable how such a fundamental feature is not built-in in the root user.